# update matplotlib figure dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some figures using matplotlib and update them dynamically
in order to do that I use set_data method as shown in the listed code
**The problem:**
when I need to highlight some point on plot for each frame , the old points are still on the plot

```
#display pics
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,4)

im3 = ax[0][3].plot(x,y)[0]

#################################################
#       some image processing code              #
#################################################

plt.ion()
for pic_index in range(no_of_pics):

    im3.set_ydata(smoothed_histogram)
    #im3.set_data(threshold,smoothed_histogram[threshold],'g*')
    ax[0][3].plot(threshold,smoothed_histogram[threshold],'r*')
    ax[0][3].plot(effective_threshold,smoothed_histogram[effective_threshold],'r*')
    
    plt.pause(0.01)
    input("Press any key to continue...")
```

the problem shown in the following figure
[image]

there should be only two red points and updated each loop

How can I overcome this problem ?

Comment: Try just adding in a `plt.cla()` which clears the current axis

Comment: i did it that way

ax[0][3].cla()
ax[0][3].plot(range(0,256),smoothed_histogram)[0]
ax[0][3].plot(threshold,smoothed_histogram[threshold],'r*')
ax[0][3].plot(effective_threshold,smoothed_histogram[effective_threshold],'r*')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You upate the `ydata` of `smoothed_histogram`, you can do the same thing with your `*` markers:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.sort(np.random.random(n))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
h_marker = ax.plot(x[0], y[0], marker='o', color='r')[0]

for i in range(n):
    h_marker.set_data(x[i], y[i])
    plt.pause(0.01)
```